# Pass a column name as an object and not a string for data.table

Tags: r, data.table, multiple-columns

I'm using data.table to make aggregation, collapse and group by. The thing is that i know a method to do this with column number but when i put a by it directly make the aggregation. I just want the collapse to be done without group by but putting the by. i know this method:

```
dt[,X := list(paste(X, collapse = ";")),by = list(Y,Z)]
```

What i want to do now is:

```
dt[,names(dt)[1] := list(paste(names(dt)[1], collapse = ";")),by = list(Y,Z)]
```

But with this code it just write me X at each line

here is an example:

```
X <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g")
Y <- c(1,2,3,4,4,6,4)
Z <- c(10,11,23,8,8,1,3)
dt <- data.table(X,Y,Z)
```

This is the desired output, but i need to now this because i'm trying to do this in multiple columns (i have a data frame with 400 columns):

```
     X Y  Z
1:   a 1 10
2:   b 2 11
3:   c 3 23
4: d;e 4  8
5:   f 6  1
6:   g 4  3
```

Comment: So what would be your end result? (expected output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wrap `names(dt)[1]` inside `get()`:

```
dt[,names(dt)[1] := list(paste(get(names(dt)[1]), collapse = ";")),by = list(Y,Z)]
```

Additionally, if you want to deduplicate your data you can use `unique(dt)`.

To apply your functions to multiple columns, you can use `.SD` in combination with `lapply()`. For example pasting together the first two cols, grouped by `Z`:

```
dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) paste(x, collapse=";")), by=list(Z),.SDcols=names(dt)[1:2]]
```

Comment: Wouldn't also `dt[,.(X = list(paste(X, collapse = ";"))),by = list(Y,Z)]` give the expected output? (minus the column position)

Comment: OP wants to use col index as far as I understood.

Comment: yep because i'll do a loop to do it in multiple columns  so the get was what i needed thanks you !!!

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to do it with multple columns in a same time ?

Comment: Something like this will also work. Add a new variable for good measure `dt[, zz := sample(letters, nrow(dt))]`. Then assign the two collapsed variables using `lapply`. `dt[, names(dt)[c(1,4)] := lapply(.SD, paste, collapse=";"), by=list(Y, Z)]`.